# Tablerates Shipping after discount

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, table-rates

I have added this piece of code in tablerates

```
$s_price = $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount();
$request->setPackageValue($s_price);
```

But it only works if you have added a shipping address but if, the check box for same as billing address is checked (Deliver to this address), shipping cost is calculating on price before discount, any help how can be this fixed.

Code looks like

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
            }
        }
    }

    // Free shipping by qty

    $s_price = $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount();
    $request->setPackageValue($s_price);

    $freeQty = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        $freePackageValue = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                        $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
            }
        }
        $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
        $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
    }

    if ($freePackageValue) {
        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $freePackageValue);
    }
    if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
        $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
        $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_default_condition_name);
    }

     // Package weight and qty free shipping
    $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
    $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

    $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $rate = $this->getRate($request);

    $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

    if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('bestway');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty)) {
            $shippingPrice = 0;
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
        }

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

        $result->append($method);
    } elseif (empty($rate) && $request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
        /**
         * was applied promotion rule for whole cart
         * other shipping methods could be switched off at all
         * we must show table rate method with 0$ price, if grand_total more, than min table condition_value
         * free setPackageWeight() has already was taken into account
         */
        $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
        $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);
        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice(0);
            $method->setCost(0);

            $result->append($method);
        }
    } else {
        $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I'm using IWD onepage checkout extension and it's probably to this extension magento default checkout works well but not and this extension